# Reusable Custom UI View w/ Parameters

Tags: swift, uiview

I have created a custom subclass of a UIView that has a Label, Image & Text Input w/ a custom .xib file. The class is meant to be an item that can easily be reused to generate a form. The Label is simply a title that goes above the Text Input & the Image is a custom icon that is shown/hidden based on if the field is required. Right now in the form, I am building it out like so :

- Instantiate a UINib of my Custom View
- Set the text of the label
- Add the instance of the UINib to an array
- After the array is built out, iterate through each item, cast it as UIView, add as a subview, and finally add constraints

My issue is this - ideally I'd like to make a custom init function where I pass in 2 parameters : Title (for the label) and a Boolean (for if it's required). I tried making a separate init, but when running the simulator, nothing appeared. It seems like I need to call the UINib(...).instantiate(...) function in order to have the actual view appear; however, I can't figure out how to assign variables during that initialization. I appreciate any feedback/suggestions/resources/etc. Thank you!

Comment: so you are trying to achieve all of that with one function  ?

Comment: Not exactly all of it, just the first 2 bullets listed. Ideally I could call something like InputElement(title: "Name:", isRequired: true) which would initialize the xib file and know to populate the Title Label's text to "Name" and show a required icon/image view due to isRequired being true

Answer (score 0):

You can write a convenience init, where you call self.init first and then apply your parameters in convenience init to your views like:

```
convenience init(title: String, isRequired: Bool) {
    self.init()
    titleLabel.text = title
    titleLabel.isHidden = isRequired
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So currently, I am initializing it from another class. I am using UINib(...).instantiate(...) . Instead, would I call my custom init? If so, would I still need to instantiate the xib somewhere? It seems like when I call the instantiate function, the class parameters I set up in my custom init are nil

Comment: Upon further research, this convenience init cannot work with xib files, it only works if view class is initialized programmatically. Sorry about confusion, You can set your views as IBInspectable to be able to edit them on xib file, but I don't think thats what you want. @JD2017